# Is a Graphics tablet essential in grease pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

I am new here but been fiddling with grease pencil. Is a Graphics tablet essential when working with grease pencil for 2D animation?

Comment: It makes animating a lot easier

Comment: right. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Oh no, definitely not. Well, technically anyway. But it means drawing with the mouse.

Comment: i got it. thanks